# Get URL parameters having URL parameters in it

Tags: php, url-parameters

I want to read URL parameters from URL and I have used `$_Get["parametername"]`. And it works fine. 
     However, for URL like : 
`http://myserver.com/getcrawledimage.php?`
`key=XXXXXXXXXX`
`&url=https://www.google.co.in/search?                     q=read+json+in+mysql&aq=f&oq=read+json+in+mysql&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.7010j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=parsing+json+in+mysql&oq=parsing+json+in+mysql&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30l3.138180.199873.3.200144.44.28.10.5.6.2.824.5388.1j22j1j1j1j0j2.28.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.6dwtA9Be9BY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.bmk&fp=cb8cca45920a2be6&biw=1920&bih=979`
`&devicetype=retina`.

it doesn't work.

I am tracking `key`, `url` and `devicetype` here. 
It returns `key=XXXXXXXXXX , url=https://www.google.co.in/search?q=read json in mysql`.
Nothing for `devicetype`. 
Can someone help me where am I wrong ?

Comment: Your URL is invalid.  You need to encode reserved characters in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant sent by url value like // or & so you can use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for value like this

```
url=<?php echo urlencode('https://www.google.co.in/search? q=read+json+in+mysql&aq=f&oq=read+json+in+mysql&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.7010j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=parsing+json+in+mysql&oq=parsing+json+in+mysql&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30l3.138180.199873.3.200144.44.28.10.5.6.2.824.5388.1j22j1j1j1j0j2.28.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.6dwtA9Be9BY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.bmk&fp=cb8cca45920a2be6&biw=1920&bih=979
&devicetype=retina.') ; ?>
```

Comment: I understand that this can be the problem. But I am new to PHP. I did not understand how can I get &devicetype value using this.

Comment: @RaviSingh, Fix the source.  The URL is fundamentally broken, and cannot be reliably be parsed.  It is ambiguous.  The original URL needs to be fixed if you expect to parse it later.